# Command Line Parameters

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I'm trying to add my file in Visual Studio as command line parameters.  I know my code works since when I use fopen("whole path here", "r"), it runs.  I then add the file as a command line parameter instead, and I get no such file or directory.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Has your file path spaces? If so, you need to enclose it in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the command line parameter is handled correctly?  Temporarily replace your main() with this:

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0;  j < argc;  ++j)
        printf ("argv [%d] = '%s'\n", j, argv [j]);
    return 0;
}
```

My guess is that you have file paths with spaces in them.  Those have to be quoted on the command line:

```
C:\> myprogram "c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Test.dat"
```

If this were unquoted, the test program would output:

```
argv [0] = 'myprogram.exe'
argv [1] = 'c:\Documents'
argv [2] = 'and'
argv [3] = 'Settings\Administrator\My'
argv [4] = 'Documents\Test.dat'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always debug in Visual Studio what file name you are getting from the command line, and then you have an idea of what's wrong.

Comment: Are you supposed to put quotes in either the Command Line Parameters in Visual Studio or fopen?  

e.g. fopen(argv[1], "r")

Comment: you have to put quotes in the Command Line Parameters in Visual Studio